# What is the best way to implement backend pagination using angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backend

I have a situation where I want to implement back end pagination but, I am not sure about how to do it. I am thinking of a solution where I fetch the total pages (a page is a  list of n defined element ) and then make call to the server to fetch 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th , .... n-th page and so on. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, pagination is done by specifying to the user how many results to display per page, and which page of results he is currently viewing. However, backend storage such as MySQL or Solr typically handle pagination by specifying how many results to display per page, and how many results to skip in the output. I generally use something like the following PHP to get the later (for the backend) out of the former (from the user):

```
$documentsPerPage = 10;

if ( isset($input['page']) && is_numeric($input['page']) && $input['page']>0 ) { 
    $skip = $documentsPerPage * (intval($input['page'])-1);
} else {
    $skip =0;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM someTable LIMIT {$skip}, {$documentsPerPage}";
```

If you have `$count` records in the database, here is how to calculate how many pages you have with a simulated floor-up operation:

```
$totalPages = ($count + $documentsPerPage - 1) % $documentsPerPage;
```

Comment: This is how you get show the n-th page, but I want to show pages 1,2,3, .... n links. I think of fetching documents info first then get each n-number document by clicking these 1,2,3 ... n links.

Comment: For each `N`th page set $input['page'] to the page number. The code as I posted it is robust, so you could use `$_GET['page']` directly without worry of SQL injection.

Comment: Terrific! The logic is right there. What is you backend storage technology? MySQL? Solr (works great with Java)?

Comment: I am using MongoDB with Java.

Comment: With MongoDB you would use the `skip()` method, like this: `db.someTable.find().skip(skip)` with the argument to `skip()` being the number calculated as above.

Comment: Thank you very mush for the help;

Comment: The think I am confused about is how to show pagination bar. like one in google from 1-10 i.e how to determine how many pages are there in the storage, before start fetching them.

Comment: Each number from the pagination bar will run a function which calculates the number of items to skip as I've posted above, and then will open the content. The specifics of how to do that will vary by your toolkit.

Comment: Yeh, but how do I initially fetch info of how many pages are there ?

Comment: Use the `.count()` method, then: `(count + documentsPerPage - 1) % documentsPerPage` to make a floor-up operation on the amount of records.